# Mosfet use to make boost converter

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics

I want to use mosfet to make a boost converter. The threshold gate to source voltage given in data sheet is 2-4 V. Then why 12-15 V is supplied? Why a resistor is connected between drain and source?

Comment: Schematic required.

Comment: Are you sure you mean drain and source?  It's common to have a (10~100k) resistor between gate and source if the gate is driven by an output that can float, forcing the gate voltage low during these floating states.

Comment: That is my doubt....Is it necessary to connect the drain to source resistance?

Answer (score 3):

The gate threshold voltage is a relatively meaningless number for designing a switching circuit.  The important number is the gate voltage at which the R<sub>DSON</sub> is specified.  For some low voltage, sometimes called *logic level* MOSFETs, that can be just below 5 V or even just below 3.3 V.  For most ordinary MOSFETs, the R<sub>DSON</sub> is specified at 10 V or so.  12 V is therefore a common value to drive the gate to.  Higher is fine, as long as it does not exceed the maximum allowed gate-source voltage.  That's often in the 15-20 V range.

A resistor is sometimes used in series with the gate to allow a little local negative feedback around the FET at high drain slew rates.  This limits the drain voltage slew rate, preventing undesirable effects inside the FET.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What about the drain to source resistance. Is it necessary to connect?